# How can I use pdb (Python debugger) in Visual Studio Code IDE's debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, pdb

I always used `pdb` for Python debugging before. Recently, I start using Visual Studio Code.

It looks in Visual Studio Code debugger, if I set a `breakpoint()`, Visual Studio Code will show variables' value at stopped position in the left window and I have to control it by a GUI bar.

So in `"integratedTerminal"` or `"externalTerminal"`, I have no control by command line which is shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and there isn't a `pdb` prompt popup. I kind of feel this surprises me since it hijacks pure Python stuff.

So is there a way to have both, the variables watch window and pdb prompt control? Especially in `"integratedTerminal"` or `"externalTerminal"`.

Below are files under folder *.vscode*,

#### File *settings.json*

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/<USERNAME>/miniconda3/envs/<CONDA_ENV>/bin/python"
}
```

#### File *launch.json*

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "python": "/Users/<USERNAME>/miniconda3/envs/<CONDA_ENV>/bin/python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/<USERNAME>/miniconda3/envs/<CONDA_ENV>/bin/<COMMAND>",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "hello-world"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the information you described, when I use "`breakpoint()`" in the code, I click <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug the code in Visual Studio Code. When the code stops, we can use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to open a new terminal and enter the pdb interactive window. At this point, we can not only see the debug variable value, but also use the 'pdb' command:

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, in my launch.json, I debug by a "program". I run this module by a entrypoint. In this case, it is ``<ENTRYPOINT CMD> hello-world``. So after vscode stopped, what command line should I use to  make sure pdb catch the same location?

Comment: @Ke Zhang -How to understand "pdb catch the same location"? Please give us an example to specify your needs.

Comment: Sure. In you example, when you use ``python -m pdb pd.py`` enter pdb interactive. ``pdb`` stopped at your ``breakpoint()`` position. This looks only true when you run a .py file directly. In my case, I source installed a package and try to test its entrypoint. My launch.json actually execute ``<CMD> hello-world`` from bash terminal. This <CMD> is a entrypoint of package. After press ``F5``, as we expect, vscode debugger stopped at breakpoint position, let's assume it's line 57 in "/Users/pkg/pkg/__init__.py",  what arguments needed for ``python -m pdb ...`` to let pdb stop at same position?

Comment: @ Ke Zhang -I set "breakpoint()" in the code, and I input "c" in the pdb interactive window to let the code execute to the position I need, it shows the number of lines at the breakpoint where it stopped.

Comment: @JillCheng Understood, you just run two times the python code, one with the built-in debugger and one with the pdb debugger. And you use the `breakpoints()` to make the pdb debugger stop as if you had the tools you use with the clicked breakpoints at the left panel in the built-in debugger. I do not think you mean here that the pdb debugger would use the same debugging run as the built-in debugger. Still handy if you like the pdb debugger, even if it is just a double run of the code, which is in itself no big trick.

Answer (score 2):

This topic bugged me too, so I opened [a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19540), where someone pointed the Debug-Console (**in Visual Studio Code next to the terminal**) out which lets you interact with Python at the point, where you're debugging. In case you don't find it directly [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2Skmwns6o8&t=424s) is a video how to do so. Once you found it, you can call arbitrary python functions in it.