# VS Code: How to launch an interactive python terminal while debugging

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have recently started using VS code for Python development. I am unable to figure out how to launch an interactive terminal while debugging, with the program state loaded-in . For example, consider the following code,

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1, 2, 3])
B = np.zeros()
C = A/B                  \\ <--- Breakpoint here
```

I want to set a breakpoint at `C = A/B` and as soon as the breakpoint hit, I want to launch an interactive terminal that holds the state of my program. So that I can play around with variables in the terminal.

This is simple and straightforward in other Python IDEs like Spyder and Pycharm. How do I do this with VS Code?

Comment: If you have VSCode's python plugin, it should only be a matter of marking the breakpoints by clicking on the left of the line number and running the main script with F5.

Comment: I am using the python extension, however, when the breakpoint hits, then the terminal is held up as well. It doesn't allow me to type anything or play around.

Comment: You should switch to the debug console tab

Comment: Check the last picture on this section: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger

Comment: Your question is strongly related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677725/how-to-use-pdbpython-debugger-in-vscode-ides-debugger sadly without an working answer too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's the [Python debugging console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) in VSCode.
When your code stops on a breakpoint, you can click on the debug console button to open an interactive Python console with your current program state loaded in.

[image: VSCode debugging screen - Microsoft Docs]

Comment: more reasons to switch from PyCharm towards VS Code

Comment: @karamqusai why? PyCharm has the same, just next to the explorer, called "console". Actually, the Python interactive console in VScode, as proposed in this answer, doesn't show up for me

Answer (score 4):

This Topic bugged me too, so I opened a [feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19540) request, where someone pointed the Debug-Console out which lets you interact with python at the point, where you're debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the debug console tab? It's usually a tab on the bottom of the VS Code screen.
[image]

Here is a video where it shows how to debug a server written in python and goes over the code using debug console: https://youtu.be/O2Skmwns6o8?t=424

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. The reason I could not find the debug console was that it was hidden. From the explorer tab, click on the top right three buttons (...) and check the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

control+shift+Y (refer dash line in the image below)

[image: View debug console]

vscode version 1.86